# How to get type backbone model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am learning **backbone** now. And I have a problem like this: can I get `type` `backbone model`. Backbone have a function like `typeof` in **javascript** or `instanceof` in **java**. Like that:

```
getModelTypeot: function(model) {
    // return model type 
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In JavaScript each object has a reference to its constructor (a function that was used to create the object). It's accessible as [`obj.constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor).

If you have a Backbone.js model, which is extended from Backbone.Model in this way: `var YourModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});`, you could create an object using `new`: `var yourModel = new YourModel();`.

Then, you could use `yourModel.constructor`:

```
yourModel.constructor === YourModel // true
```

Or [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof):

```
yourModel instanceof YourModel // true
yourModel instanceof Backbone.Model // true
```